# RecyclerView Data get repeated after pull to refresh and at simultaneously Tab Changes in TabView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pull-to-refresh, tabview

I have `TabView` with 3 Tab in `MainActivity`.I have set data on Tab1 using `RecyclerView`. Recyclerview is in `SwipeRefreshView`.When I pull to refresh recyclerview and at same time within second I changed tab the data in RecyclerView at Tab1 get double,triple.How to resolve this to avoid data duplication on Pull to refresh.
This is  code to Pull to refresh

```
pullRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String NetworkStatus = biz.fyra.bookapp.utils.NetworkStatus.checkConnection(getContext());
                        if (NetworkStatus.equals("false")) {
                            pullRefresh.setEnabled(false);
                            pullRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        } else {
                            pullRefresh.setEnabled(true);
                            //pullRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
                            db.deleteAllQueueFoodieDB();
                            checkInternet();
                        }


                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: When you call swipe to refresh just clear the arraylist..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `arraylist.clear()` method and recyclerView will not repeat its content after refresh.

**Basically** `arraylist.clear()` removes all the elements from arraylist.